# Laravel Validation of password failed, when it must be ok. Why?

Tags: php, laravel, validation

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
                'email' => 'required|min:9|max:50|email',
                'password' => 'required|min:8|max:255|password'
            ]);

            if ($validator->fails()) {
                echo "Failed! Sorry :(";
                Session::flash('error', $validator->messages()->first());
                //return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validator);
            }
            else {...
```

But if I write

```
'password' => 'required|min:8|max:255'
```

the validation is passed, but when I write

```
'password' => 'required|min:8|max:255|password'
```

it doesn't pass and the result is "Failed! Sorry :(". I mean that works the echo which I wrote above.
What can be the problem? Or the "password" is excessive? I am newbie in Laravel.

Important! The password in database is being saved hashed.

Comment: `if ($validator->fails(){ dd($validator->errors()); }`; that should tell you _why_ your validation is failing, so you can debug it further 

Comment: thanks. But it says the thing I already know by my  own logics, that the problem is that password is incorrect. But the fact is the password is correct in reality, but the code don't want to agree.

Comment: Is this validation on login? Or when registering a new user? Are you wanting to check this password against a specific User? I'm not sure what you're trying to do here...

Comment: @TimLewis this is for login.

Comment: The `password` rule checks against the currently authenticated user. If you're using this on login, **when there is no currently authenticated user**, this will not work. Remove the `password` rule, validate the presence/length, then, after validation, use `auth()->check()` instead.

Comment: @TimLewis auth()-check() what it does? Can the check give error if my password in database is hashed?

Comment: `auth()->check()` takes the email/username and unhashed password and checks if that's the correct password for the User trying to login. You can do something like `if(!auth()->check($request->input('email'), $request->input('password')){ return back()->with('error', 'Incorrect Password'); }`

Comment: @TimLewis ok, Thanks for help.

Comment: I might have the wrong method, `attempt` instead of `check`, will have to double check, but that's the general idea; validate presence/length, check if correct, login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `password` validation rule checks the field under validation against the current authenticated user's password. So you shouldn't use it if you want to check only it's length. If you want more specific validation rules, you can use regex. For example, this rule checks if the given password contains at least one small letter, one capital letter and a digit and it's length shouldn't be less than 8:

```
'password' => 'required|min:8|regex:#(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])#'
```